# OpenGL fragment shader doesn't write to SSBO

Tags: opengl

I have a small OpenGL engine written and I want to use SSBOs to allow shaders to write debugging logs that I can write out. My log class looks like this:

```
#define SHADER_LOG_LINE_LENGTH 128
#define SHADER_LOG_MAX_LINES 512
#define SHADER_LOG_DATA_OFFSET sizeof(int32_t) * 3
#define SHADER_LOG_DATA_SIZE SHADER_LOG_LINE_LENGTH * SHADER_LOG_MAX_LINES * sizeof(int32_t)
#define SHADER_LOG_TOTAL_SIZE SHADER_LOG_DATA_OFFSET + SHADER_LOG_DATA_SIZE

class ShaderLog
  {
    protected:
      GLuint ssbo;
      GLuint binding_point;

      int32_t number_of_lines;
      int32_t max_lines;
      int32_t line_length;
      int32_t data[SHADER_LOG_DATA_SIZE];

    public:
      ShaderLog()
        {
          glGenBuffers(1,&(this->ssbo));

          this->number_of_lines = 0;
          this->max_lines = SHADER_LOG_MAX_LINES;
          this->line_length = SHADER_LOG_LINE_LENGTH;
          this->binding_point = 0;

          glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,this->ssbo);
          glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,SHADER_LOG_TOTAL_SIZE,&(this->number_of_lines),GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
          glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,this->binding_point,this->ssbo);
          glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,0);
        };

      void connect_to_shader(Shader *shader, string shader_variable_name)
        {
          GLuint block_index = 0;
          block_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(shader->get_shader_program_number(),GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK,shader_variable_name.c_str());

          if (block_index == GL_INVALID_INDEX)
            ErrorWriter::write_error("Shader log could not be connected to the shader.");

          glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,block_index,this->binding_point);
          glShaderStorageBlockBinding(shader->get_shader_program_number(),block_index,this->binding_point);
        }

      virtual void load_from_gpu()
        {
          glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,this->ssbo);
          GLvoid* mapped_ssbo = glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,GL_READ_ONLY);

          if (mapped_ssbo == NULL)
            ErrorWriter::write_error("Could not map shader log into client's memory space for reading.");
          else
            memcpy(&(this->number_of_lines),mapped_ssbo,SHADER_LOG_DATA_SIZE);

          glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
        }

      int get_number_of_lines()
        {
          return this->number_of_lines;
        }

     ...
  };
```

In my fragment shader I do:

```
#version 430

layout (std430, binding=0) buffer shader_log_data
  {
    int number_of_lines;
    int max_lines;
    int line_length;
    int data[];
  } shader_log;

...

void main()
  {
    shader_log.number_of_lines = 20;  // just to test
    shader_log.data[0] = 10000;

    ...
  }
```

And the main program looks like this:

```
void render()
  {        
    ... // rendering

    shader_log->load_from_gpu();
    cout << "lines: " << shader_log->get_number_of_lines() << endl;

    glutSwapBuffers();
  }

...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
  { 
    ...
    shader_log = new ShaderLog();
    ...
    shader_log->connect_to_shader(shader,"shader_log_data");
    shader_log->update_gpu();
    ...
    // rendering loop
    ...
  }
```

Now the number of lines written out remains 0, even though it should be set to 20 by the shader. I tried loading the data from GPU after glBufferData(...) and they are there, the problem seems to be in the connection between the buffer and the shader. I also tried reading the data in the shader and outputting them to screen and they're always 0, which supports my hypothesis. Basically I seem to be able to write/read to/from the SSBO from the CPU but not from the shader. Could anyone help me with finding the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you pass binding_point (which is 0) to your memcpy function? This way you get 0 bytes of data copied.

```
memcpy(&(this->number_of_lines),mapped_ssbo,this->binding_point);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's one bug, I replaced it with SHADER_LOG_TOTAL_SIZE. Still doesn't work though :/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that at least one of those ... lines is a memory barrier that you neglected to show?

You need some form of synchronization across parallel invocations to ensure coherency, this is not automagic when using SSBOs, Image Load/Store, etc. You are likely to read an undefined value without a barrier in place as each execution unit has a different (isolated) view of the same memory.

Making sure that changes you made to the SSBO are visible to other shader invocations will require a barrier in your GLSL code prior to performing the read. Other types of incoherent operations may require a barrier in the GL command stream, but the premise is the same; order commands and read/write memory such that following operations use the result of previous ones.

Comment: My plan is to use atomicAdd(...) function in the shader to "allocate" a part of the buffer (a single "line" in the log) for each shader invocation that wants to write to the log. This code should only test that after writing a value to the buffer in the shader the value is retrieveable from the CPU. I know I need to use synchronization later, but now since all shader only write, the code should be OK, right?